# html <script> tag does not recognise variables defined in it

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, web-applications

I'm using google map service and so following a tutorial from google map plat form:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3MjU9E9buQ&t=99s&ab_channel=GoogleMapsPlatform
As the same in the video at 1:37, I'm defining a variable `autocomplete` in the `<script>` tag, but when I run the code, there's an error:

```
  Line 50:21:  'autocomplete' is not defined  no-undef
```

And here is the code I use `NewHotel.js`:

```
 import { useState } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import AlgoliaPlaces from 'algolia-places-react';
import { GoogleCircleFilled } from "@ant-design/icons";

const config = {
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_ALGOLIA_API_KEY,
    language: "en",
    countries: ["nl"],
}

const NewHotel = () => {
    // state
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        title: '',
        content: '',
        location: '',
        image: '',
        price: '',
        from: '',
        to: '',
        bed: '',  // how many pages are available

    });
    // destructuring variables from state
    const [preview, setPreview] = useState(
        "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100.png?text=PREVIEW");
    const {title, content, location, image, price, from, to, bed} = values;
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {

    };
    const handleImageChange = (e) => {
        // console.log(e.target.files[0]);
        setPreview(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
        setValues({...values, image: e.target.files[0] });
    };
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setValues({...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    };
    
    const hotelForm = () => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <script async
                src={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY}&libraries=places&callback=initMap`}>
            </script>
            <script>
                let autocomplete;
                function initAutoComplete() {
                    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                        document.getElementById('autocomplete'),
                        {
                            types: ['establishment'],
                            componentRestrictions: {'country': ['NL']},
                            fields: ['place_id', 'geometry', 'name'],
                        },
                    )
                }
            </script>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block m-2 text-left">
                    Image
                    <input 
                        type="file" 
                        name="image" 
                        onChange={handleImageChange} 
                        accept="image/*" 
                        hidden 
                    />
                </label>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    name="title" 
                    onChange={handleChange} 
                    placeholder="Title" 
                    className="form-control m-2" 
                    value={title} 
                />

                <textarea
                    name="content" 
                    onChange={handleChange} 
                    placeholder="Content" 
                    className="form-control m-2" 
                    value={content} 
                />

                <input
                    id="autocompletelocation"
                    className="form-control ml-2 mr-2" 
                    placeholder="Location" 
                    defaultValue={location} 
                    options={config} 
                    onChange={({suggestion}) =>
                     setValues({...values, location: suggestion.value})}  // suggestion is a prop
                    style={{height: "50px"}}
                />

                <input 
                    type="number" 
                    name="price" 
                    onChange={handleChange} 
                    placeholder="Price" 
                    className="form-control m-2" 
                    value={price} 
                />

                <input 
                    type="number" 
                    name="bed" 
                    onChange={handleChange} 
                    placeholder="Number of Beds" 
                    className="form-control m-2" 
                    value={bed} 
                />
            </div>

            <button className="btn m-2 btn-outline-primary">Save</button>
        </form>
    )

    return (
        <>
        <div className="container-fluid bg-secondary p-5 text-center">
            <h2>Add Hotel</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-10">
                    <br />
                    {hotelForm()}
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-2">
                    <img src={preview} alt="preview_image" className="img img-fluid m-2" />
                    <pre>
                        {JSON.stringify(values, null, 4)}
                    </pre>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
};

export default NewHotel;
```

`App.js`:

```
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute';
// components
import Home from './booking/Home';
import Login from './auth/Login';
import Register from './auth/Register';
import React from 'react';
import TopNav from './components/TopNav';
import Dashboard from './user/Dashboard';
import DashboardSeller from './user/DashboardSeller';
import NewHotel from './hotels/NewHotel';
import StripeCallback from './stripe/StripeCallback';


function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter forceRefresh>
      <TopNav />
      <ToastContainer />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard/seller" component={DashboardSeller} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/hotels/new" component={NewHotel} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/stripe/callback" component={StripeCallback} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Besides, usually when we declare or define a variable, its color is changed by the editor, but I notice that the color of the variable `complete` does not change, which means that the editor does not recognised it as a variable. The function I defined here has the same problem
[image]

Comment: This is neither valid HTML nor valid JavaScript. What is this?

Comment: @FelixKling I want to use google map service so the code is following the tutorial from google map platform (starting at 1:37 of the video): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3MjU9E9buQ&t=99s&ab_channel=GoogleMapsPlatform

Comment: The video doesn't seem to suggest to do `const hotelForm = () => ( <Form ...`. So again, what is this?

Comment: @FelixKling it is a component I use on a page. I have editted my code and pasted all the .js file.

Comment: So you missed tagging react. Why do you use inline JS in React when you can use React? https://www.google.com/search?q=react+autocomplete

Comment: @mplungjan I want to use Google map autocomplete and I don't know how to embed it into React autocomplete

Comment: Seems others do: https://www.google.com/search?q=google+map+autocomplete+react

Comment: try moving `let autoComplete` inside the function and check if it works